# P-branes (extended objects) with multime time-like dimensions

Tags: time, spacetime-dimensions, branes

Why M-theory/supestring theory restrict itself to one time-like (internal!) dimension (excepting F and S-theory)? After all a brane with $X^\mu(\sigma,\tau$) can be extended in principle to $X^\mu(\vec{\sigma},\vec{\tau})$...I believe it is due to the conformal invariance (2d) of strings in higher dimensional objects and, generally speaking, to stability issues and consistency (higher spin theories of interacting fields are complex, as that of Vassiliev)...How can be interpreted higher dimensional world-tube dimensions?

After all, accordingly to some supersymmetric researchers, interesting stuff happens with multiple time-like dimensions, for instance, the remarkable paper by Toppan et. al.: 
http://cds.cern.ch/record/605786/files/0302113.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Itzak Bars has various ideas of two time physics. You can find him [here](http://physics.usc.edu/~bars/twoTph.htm) and a paper on this [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1004.0688). These ideas are not without some plausible merit. The $AdS_5$ spacetime sits in a spacetime with $2$ time dimensions, but where the additional time is at a constant or zero value. The idea of two time directions in physics is out there some.